# Call Twiml Object in Codeigniter - Twilio service

Tags: php, codeigniter, twilio, twilio-twiml

I am integrating twilio service in codeigniter. But currently, I don't know how to call Twiml object. In raw PHP, I can just code like this:

```
use Twilio\Twiml;
$response = new Twiml();
```

But in codeigniter, I can only call the library twilio service (which i put in libraries folder) and cannot use Twiml object in controller.

```
$this->load->library( 'twilio_services' );
```

This is where I download twilio service:
https://github.com/t1gr0u/codeigniter-twilio/tree/master/libraries

I try to search everywhere but can't find it. Anyone can help me.

Comment: Please show how you wrote `twilio_services` library

Comment: I download twilio_services from here:
https://github.com/t1gr0u/codeigniter-twilio/tree/master/libraries

Comment: Which version of codeigniter you are using ?

Comment: im using vr 3.1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**An alternate approach**

Download [Twilio PHP SDK](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/archive/5.16.1.zip) and put it into the folder third_party

Copy this file and put into library folder as `Btwilio.php`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

require_once APPPATH.'third_party/twilio/Twilio/autoload.php' ;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
use Twilio\TwiML      ;  // TwiML used

class Btwilio {

    private $btwilio ;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $AccountSid = "AC008e63cc03eec3be4b1cfe7ab80478a0";
        $AuthToken = "82496aa3278d9cbebfc0f24ae1c1ba7f";



        $this->btwilio = new Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

        $this->btwiml  = new Twiml();

    }


    public function sendsms()
    {

        $people = array(
        "+919048XXXXXX" => "Rajeev"
        );

        // Step 5: Loop over all our friends. $number is a phone number above, and 
        // $name is the name next to it
        foreach ($people as $number => $name) {

            $sms = $this->btwilio->account->messages->create(

                // the number we are sending to - Any phone number
                $number,

                array(
                    // Step 6: Change the 'From' number below to be a valid Twilio number 
                    // that you've purchased
                    'from' => "+18559063122", 

                    // the sms body
                    'body' => "Hey $name, Monkey Party at 6PM. Bring Bananas!"
                )
            );

            // Display a confirmation message on the screen
            echo "Sent message to $name";
        }


    }


    public function sendtwiml()
    {

        // $this->btwiml  = new Twiml();  use $this->btwiml to use Twiml services



        // Step 5: Loop over all our friends. $number is a phone number above, and 
        // $name is the name next to it
        //$response = new Twiml();
        $this->btwiml->sms('The king stay the king.', ['from' => '+14105551234',
            'to' => '+919048309695']);

        print_r($this->btwiml) ;


    }


}

/* End of file Btwilio.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/Btwilio.php */
```

Call this library on your controller like

```
$this->load->library('btwilio');

$this->btwilio->sendsms() ; // method created on Btwilio library

$this->btwilio->sendtwiml() ; // method of TwiML example
```

Create custom Methods in this library which can use from official Twilio

[Link is Here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/sending-via-rest#send-sms-via-rest)

You have to use `$this->btwilio` because we have instantiated to this one

Comment: I wonder is there anyway I can use Twiml. But yours is a good way to approach. Thanks

Comment: Please check the updated code . I have implemented TwiML service .

Comment: Thanks. Its what i need!